# Абстрактный класс-Singleton на java

Tags: java

Некоторое время назад писал на юнити. Использовал на шарпе такой класс:

```
public abstract class MySingleton<T>
{
    private static T _instance;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public static void ForgetInstance()
    {
        _instance = default(T);
    }

    protected MySingleton()
    {

    }
```

Можно ли как-то извернуться, чтобы написать похоже на java?

В лоб то, говорит: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T"

---

Comment: Вам точно вообще нужен синглтон?

Comment: Боюсь что реализация Generics в Java такого не позволяет, без злобных костылей с reflection которые сделаю код совершенно невменяемым. Так что расскажите зачем вам это надо?

Comment: Боюсь, что type erasure не позволит вам сделать такое. По коду: вы бы наложили generic constraint `where T : class`.

Comment: (Потому что синглтон практически не может быть value-typed)

Comment: `public abstract class MySingleton<T> where T : new` ... `_instance = new T();` Это как улучшить код на шарпе. Про джаву не знаю.

Comment: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T" - а нельзя ли сделать T статическим?

Comment: Ребята, мне кажется у нас какое-то недопонимание. Особенно после поста @Tagir Valeev. В основном я использую Ioc для проектов (android). Но не знаю, мне как-то привычней обращаться непосредственно к классу по имени.
Нужен ли мне синглтон - думаю что да. Но точно не для таких объектов как string. Это будет какой-то мой класс - один на всё приложение. Таких классов будет очень немного. Но в любом случае сейчас мне приходится писать один и тот же участок кода для этих классов вручную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, хочется хранить по одному объекту для каждого запрошенного класса, созданному с помощью конструктора по умолчанию. Для этой цели можно завести `ConcurrentHashMap<Class<?>, Object>`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class MySingleton {
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<Class<?>, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
        T object = (T) map.get(clazz);
        if(object == null) {
            try {
                object = clazz.newInstance();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException
                         | SecurityException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
            T oldObject = (T) map.putIfAbsent(clazz, object);
            if(oldObject != null) // ой, другой поток вперёд успел
                return oldObject;
        }
        return object;
    }

    public static void forgetInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
        map.remove(clazz);
    }
}
```

Соответственно использовать как-то так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = MySingleton.getInstance(String.class);
    String str2 = MySingleton.getInstance(String.class);
    System.out.println(str == str2); // true
    MySingleton.forgetInstance(String.class);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Статическую generic-переменную создать не получится.
Если переменная должна быть статичной, чтобы конкретизировать строго одну переменную на класс, то можно попробовать создать статичный экземпляр класса и оперировать уже с ним. Инициировать такой экземпляр класса можно через конструктор.

```
// T-переменная нестатична
private T _instance;
/* Tclass = T.class
 * запоминаем для упрощения, инициируем в конструкторе
 */
private static Class<?> Tclass;
/* Статический элемент класса MySingleton
 * класс непараметризован, чтобы остаться статическим
 */
private static MySingleton mysingleton;

// Конструктор создает экземпляр синглтон-класса
protected MySingleton(){
    mysingleton = new MySingleton<T>(){};
    Tclass = ((Class<?>)((ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
}
```

Вернуть из статического метода generic-переменную, опять-таки, не получится. Тут есть два возможных выхода:
1) Создать экземпляр класса через уже имеющийся конструктор и обращаться впредь к нестатичному методу
2) Если T является подклассом Object, то статический класс может возвращать Object

Дефолтное же значение Т-переменной можно получить, например, через конструктор:
    Tclass.getConstructor().newInstance()